# Getting specific index's from array using numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have the following array in python (using numpy):

```
arr = np.linspace(1, 48, 48).reshape(3, 4, 4)
```

I need to reshape and print out the following from the array which I am battling with:

1) [[1. 4.] [45. 48.]]

2) [[25. 26. 27. 28.], [29. 30. 31. 32.], [33. 34. 35. 36.], [37. 38. 39. 40.]]

I tried many different approaches but cant seem to get a clean cut and efficient means to accomplish this.

Comment: what are the rules? only reshaping and slicing allowed? because with advanced indexing it is kind of trivial...

Comment: flatten and reshape is preferred

Comment: Have you found any means?  Forget about the 'clean cut' and 'efficient' for the moment, and show us what you have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
arr.reshape(12,4)[6:10,:]
arr.reshape(12,4)[::11,::3]
```

might be interesting to find a rule for when a riddle of this kind can be solved and when not. or teach a computer to solve them.